# The foundation 5 docs on get.foundation/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/ are not available anymore

Tags: zurb-foundation, documentation, zurb-foundation-5

Today I found that the documentation for foundation 5 (https://get.foundation/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/) is not available anymore and I still have projects in long term maintenance that rely on version 5.

Considering the discussion on Github about Zurb distanzing itself from foundation, I wonder if this a short term hicup or if zurb actually taken down the version 5 docs...

Anyway, does anybody know of a secondary source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have reuploaded them at https://get.foundation/sites/docs-v5/

Is there still an old / wrong link in the current docs?

Comment: Hi Daniel, just search for 'foundation 5 docs' with google or duckduckgo and you will get results still pointing to the old url.

Comment: Ah right. Well we need some redirects there. But the new docs do work and v5 docs are available again.